# Keep Google Cloud Jupyter Notebook Running while computer sleeps

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

So I want to run a neural network on Google Cloud instance, but whenever my computer goes to sleep the notebook seems to stop running. Does anyone know how I can keep it running?

Comment: not sure if there's a way to do that but what I did was just changed the sleep settings to never sleep. on windows I just searched "sleep settings"

Comment: That is very insufficient. That can work for desktop users, but what about laptops? I did set my Mac to not sleep, but that only works when it's plugged in. If the computer gets unplugged, it will fall asleep soon after. Even if you manage to never accidentally unplug the computer, you will need to on purpose sometimes. What about when  I need to take the computer back and forth between home and work or school?

Comment: I fully suspect that your notebook doesn't actually stop running. I found that in my case, the web socket shut down when my laptop went to screensaver. When I turned it back on I had a small heart-attack because I thought I had lost the 6 hours of data processing I was doing in a jupyter notebook. However, after a minute I got a message saying that my notebook had been changed on disk and asked me if I wanted to load these changes. When I did, I saw that the process was still running... is running now. I've got about 4 more hours to go, barring any catastrophes.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered this huge oversight in GCP. I don't understand how they could design it this way. This behavior defeats a major point of using the cloud. They want us to pay for this? I use a laptop which sometimes needs to be asleep in a backpack, I can't keep a computer on all day just so a cloud computer can run.

If I can't figure anything else out, we are just going to have to use two cloud computers. Maybe use like a small free cloud computer to keep the big datalab one running. We shouldn't have to resort to this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but let me give it a shot. When you say Google Cloud instance do you mean their **compute engine (virtual machine)**? If so, you don't need to keep your laptop running all the time to continue a process on cloud, there is an alternative. You can run your python programs from terminal and use tools like **Screen** or **tmux**, which keep running your (training) process even if your GC instance is disconnected. You can even turn your system off. I just finished a 24 hr long Hyperparameter optimization *marathon* few days back.
Allow me to also mention here that sometimes "Screen" throws X11 display related errors, so tmux can be used instead.

**Usage Instructions:**

- Install tmux : sudo apt-get install tmux
- start new tmux session to run your process : tmux new -s "name_of_sess" --> this opens a new window in terminal. Type your command here like : python my_program.py to start your training.
- detach session : ctrl+B -> release -> press 'd' (while inside session)
- list of all the tmux session running : tmux ls
- attach a session : tmux attach -t "id_from_above_command_lists"
- kill a tmux session : ctrl+shift+d

Note: Commands are mentioned based on what I remember, it may have mistakes. Quick search would give you exact syntax. Idea is to show how easy it is to use.

Answer (score 0):

In the remote (GCP) SSH client:

- Install tmux: `sudo apt-get install tmux`.
- Start a new tmux session: `tmux new -s "session"`.
- Run commands as normal.